# Create an Android 2.2 (api 8) app using cordova

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I am trying to make an android app using cordova. The apk file created by cordova as a result of the following lines

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$ cd hello
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova build
```

is not supported by the emulator in which I have installed Android 2.2 (api 8).It gives the following error message.

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

It works fine on Android 4.4.1. I would like to create an apk file supported by Android 2.2 also. Is it possible?

If possible where should I specify the api version?

Answer (score 0):

Reading is good.

- [Official Apache Cordova Blog](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/)
- [Official Adobe Phonegap Blog](https://phonegap.com/blog/)

[Android (Cordova) Platform Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

> Cordova supports Android 4.0.x (starting with Android API level 14)
>   and higher. As a general rule, Android versions become unsupported by
>   Cordova as they dip below 5% on Google's distribution dashboard.
>   Android versions earlier than API level 10, and the 3.x versions
>   (Honeycomb, API levels 11-13) fall significantly below that 5%
>   threshold.

Comment: I really want to build an app which support android 2.2. Does this mean that there is no way to build an app for api 8 with cordova? The app works fine on android 2.3 api 10 anyway.

Comment: You can build your app to with Android SDK v10, but not SDK v8. I cannot say if it will run with Android 2.2.